# wordpress (nextgen gallery) showing alt (image attribute) as text after the image in the front end

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

my problem is the title says, wordpress keeps on showing the alt attribute as text after the image on the front end.

FRONT end
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8oeU.png

BACK end

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxDt3.png

Comment: Do you have a link to the project? Seeing the generated front end html would help to identify where the broken tags are.

Comment: yes it is there on the back end link (www.ccbarranca.org.co/festival)
anyways, this i think is causing the error: 
`code`
  <!-- Pagination -->
 <div class='ngg-clear'></div> </div>
"  alt="" data-mce-placeholder="1" /></noscript></p>
                </div> 
but using another theme doesnt show the alt as text